# How to prevent google contact response being received by google calendar request

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api, google-api-client, google-api-dotnet-client

We have been using the Google Contact and Calendar API successfully for years via the c# client libraries (Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.1.9.2.1330). An unusual error has started happening recently. It appears that a calendar API call is getting a contact API response (see below). Has anyone come across this before and have a solution to prevent it happening again?

EDIT:
including code snippet:

```
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;
using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Http;
using Google.Apis.Services;

...

var eventList = service.Events.List(calendarListEntry.Id);
eventList.TimeMin = dateFrom;
eventList.TimeMax = dateTo;
eventList.SingleEvents = true;
var events = eventList.Execute().Items;
```

EDIT: So here is an example of this happening. I have taken anything sensitive out of the log but the sequence of events is. 1. we see two successful API requests and responses. 2. we get a 404 response but weirdly that results an parsing exception as if the response contained xml or at least something  begining with '<'. 3. A subsequent request for the same URI returns a 200

```
1.
    "63577099854207364450, Request https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList, req auth:Bearer xxx, headers:User-Agent: Datahug google-api-dotnet-client/1.9.3.19379 (gzip)
    Authorization: Bearer xxx
    , Thread50"
    "63577099854637364450, Request https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/eaxmple@domain.com/events?singleEvents=True&timeMax=2016-03-06T01:30:53.873Z&timeMin=2016-02-05T01:30:53.873Z, req auth:Bearer xxx, headers:User-Agent: Datahug google-api-dotnet-client/1.9.3.19379 (gzip)
    Authorization: Bearer xxx
    , Thread50"
    "63577099854207364450, Request https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList, req auth:Bearer xxx, Thread41, result:StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
    {
      Vary: Origin
      Vary: X-Origin
      X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
      X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
      X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
      Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=1
      Alt-Svc: quic="":443""; p=""1""; ma=604800
      Transfer-Encoding: chunked
      Cache-Control: no-transform, must-revalidate, max-age=0, private
      Date: Sun, 06 Sep 2015 01:30:54 GMT
      Server: GSE
      Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
      Expires: Sun, 06 Sep 2015 01:30:54 GMT
    }"
    "63577099854637364450, Request https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/eaxmple@domain.com/events?singleEvents=True&timeMax=2016-03-06T01:30:53.873Z&timeMin=2016-02-05T01:30:53.873Z, req **auth:Bearer xxx**, Thread29, result:StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
    {
      Vary: Origin
      Vary: X-Origin
      X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
      X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
      X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
      Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=1
      Alt-Svc: quic="":443""; p=""1""; ma=604800
      Transfer-Encoding: chunked
      Cache-Control: no-transform, must-revalidate, max-age=0, private
      Date: Sun, 06 Sep 2015 01:30:54 GMT
      Server: **GSE**
      Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
      Expires: Sun, 06 Sep 2015 01:30:54 GMT
    }"
    "63577099856222364450, Request https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList, req auth:Bearer yyy, headers:User-Agent: Datahug google-api-dotnet-client/1.9.3.19379 (gzip)
    Authorization: Bearer yyy
    , Thread50"
2.    "63577099856222364450, Request https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList, req **auth:Bearer yyy**, Thread42, result:StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
    {
      Connection: close
      Date: Sun, 06 Sep 2015 01:30:56 GMT
      Server: **GFE/2.0**
      Content-Length: 1527
      Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    }"
    An Error occurred, but the error response could not be deserialized|The service calendar has thrown an exception: Google.GoogleApiException: An Error occurred, but the error response could not be deserialized ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: **Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <.** Path '', line 0, position 0.
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal()
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
       at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
       at Google.Apis.Json.NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input) in c:\ApiaryDotnet\default\Src\GoogleApis.Core\Apis\Json\NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.cs:line 120
       at Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.<DeserializeError>d__8.MoveNext() in c:\ApiaryDotnet\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Services\BaseClientService.cs:line 286
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at Google.Apis.Requests.ClientServiceRequest`1.Execute() in c:\ApiaryDotnet\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\Requests\ClientServiceRequest.cs:line 102
       at DataIntegration.Services.Google.ImportGmailCalenderService.ImportGmailCalendars(DateTime dateFrom, DateTime dateTo, Boolean validateResultsAreForCorrectAccount, ISet`1 internalDomainUrls, String email, String account) in c:\buildworkspaces\WebApp-BuildUnitTest-NextRelease\NextRelease\DataIntegration\Services\Google\ImportGmailCalendarService.cs:line 59


3.    "63577099858032364450, Request https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList, req auth:Bearer yyy, headers:User-Agent: Datahug google-api-dotnet-client/1.9.3.19379 (gzip)
    Authorization: Bearer yyy
    , Thread50"
    "63577099858032364450, Request https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList, req auth:Bearer yyy, Thread39, result:StatusCode: 200, ReasonPhrase: 'OK', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
    {
      Vary: Origin
      Vary: X-Origin
      X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
      X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
      X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
      Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic,p=1
      Alt-Svc: quic="":443""; p=""1""; ma=604800
      Transfer-Encoding: chunked
      Cache-Control: no-transform, must-revalidate, max-age=0, private
      Date: Sun, 06 Sep 2015 01:30:58 GMT
      Server: GSE
      Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
      Expires: Sun, 06 Sep 2015 01:30:58 GMT
    }"
```

A couple of things of note: The auth bearer token has just been changed before the problematic request/response. The server in the error response is different than in the successful responses.

Comment: Could you post your code looks like you are trying to mix XML and Json.  Calendar V3 returns JSon contacts API is an old gdata API and returns xml.   By default they probably wont play nicely together.

Comment: Hi DalmTo, yes an exception is thrown because the response is a json contact response belonging to anther thread but its not clear why it is being received by an calendar api client call. I've included the line where the exception occurs in the question (var events = eventList.Execute().Items;). thanks for you help

Comment: put a try catch around some of your code. that doesn't return that error.  I need the code that causes the error.   The current google .net client library does not talk to the old gData api they are two different systems.

Comment: output the value of calendarListEntry.Id

Comment: ImportGmailCalendarService.cs:line 59 == "var events = eventList.Execute().Items;"

Comment: I just ran that code it works fine and has nothing to do with the gdata library.   what is the value of calendarListEntry.Id  ?   Is service an authenticated CalendarService?

Comment: We use the old gData library for contacts but the line where the exception is thrown is from Google.Apis.Calendar.v3 i.e. var events = eventList.Execute().Items; . It might be there is some dependency between the contacts gdata library and the calendar library

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88680/discussion-between-daimto-and-bettlebrox).